# How to plot $X=|1-2y|$ in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

Suppose if i know the plot of $x$

```
set.seed(650)
x = c(rnorm(100))
Index = 1:100
plot(Index,x, type = "l")
```

[image]

Since, $X = |1-2Y|$. Thus, $\pm X = 1-2Y$. So, $Y = \frac{1}{2}(1\pm X)$.

My question is, how do I construct a graph in `r` $Y$ against `index`?

Thank you for your idea.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to plot y against x (as suggested by your title) or y against the index (as suggested by your second last line?

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.** Probably not an answer because the question and its motivation are unclear. As you show, this is not a 1-to-1 function.

Plot $y$ against index, showing two possible values in different colors.

```
plot(.5*(1+x), type="l", col="blue", ylab="y") 
  lines(.5*(1-x), type="l", col="brown")  # add lines to existing plot
  abline(h=.5, col="green2")
```

[image]

Plot $y$ against $x$ (one possible style), again with colors representing alternate values.

```
plot(x, .5*(1-x), type="b", col="blue", ylim=c(min(.5*(1-x)), max(.5*(1+x))), ylab="y")
  lines(x, .5*(1+x), type="b", col="brown")
```

[image]

*Note:* Your original code can be simplified, as follows. `Index` need not be specified, if there is only one numerical argument for `plot`. (Please look at documentation for `plot`.)

```
set.seed(650)
x = rnorm(100)
plot(x, type = "l")
```

[image]